# shower water turns from hot to cold when just turning handle a hair

Tags: shower

When turning the handle in shower from hot a hair the water gets cold not warm and handle position is just a hair from fully hot.  I have a gas water heater.  I also had a plummer change the regulater valve in shower but still have same problem.

Comment: Do you experience this problem in any other fixtures in the house?  Who is the mfg of the valve?  How old is it? Is this a single handle valve?  Can you get a model number off the valve?

Comment: Do you have a tank water heater or tankless?

Comment: What is the temperature of the hot water coming out of the shower?  What s the temperature setting on your hot water heater? Is the temperature regulator valve part of the shower valve or is it a separate valve?